# How to use IF AND statement with events

Tags: vb.net

I want to do something if both a Listbox Item is selected and a Button is clicked. What I'm thinking is like this but it clearly isn't correct.

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 And btnConvert_click Then
```

(This is under the `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` Private Sub)

Comment: I think you have to rethink your logic, or explain what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Do you mean if the button is clicked at least once and so is the listbox item? Because it would be really hard for a user to simultaneously do both things.

Comment: You would check which index of the listbox is selected when you click the button. They cannot select both.

Comment: @davidsbro I mean if the list box item is already selected and then a button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do something like this

```
Private sub btnConvert_click (sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click

    If Combo.SelectedIndex > -1 Then ' SelectedIndex= -1 --> nothing selected

        ' Do your code
    End If

End Sub
```

And in your case you wouldn't use Combo_Selected. This is if you want select the item and click the button. Remember, first item has index "0".